# Can't pass var (which is a function) as argument in another function

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, arguments

I don't think I need to explain much about this little piece of code:

```
function autoTab(){
    var focus = focusCheck();
    var length = lengthCheck(focus);
    console.log(focus + length);
}

function focusCheck(){
    return document.activeElement.id;
}

function lengthCheck(a){
   var inputLength = a.value.length;
   return inputLength;
}
```

Anyways I want to make an autotab function where you automatically tab once a certain character limit has been reached in the input box.

right now I need the argument for lengthCheck() to be the return value of focusCheck().

The function focusCheck() looks for the element that has focus, I want lengthCheck to check the value length of the right input box, so it has to be the one that focusCheck() returns.

Right now I get an error that says "a.value is undefined".
Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: `focusCheck` returns only the **id**. I don't think the id has a `.value`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The function focusCheck() looks for the element that has focus

And it returns that element's **id**, which is a string.

> I want lengthCheck to check the value length of the right input box

Then you need to access the value of the **element**, not the value of the **id**.

Either return the element itself in the first place or use `getElementById`.